# Change the order of columns using Pandas dataframe and drop a column

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have the following an illustrative example dataframe df

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'name': ['A', 'B', 'C'],
                'value': [100, 300, 150]})
```

The real dataframe has much more columns and rows. As I said this is only an illustrative example.

I want to change the order of the columns, so that I get the following result:

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'name': ['A', 'C', 'B'],
                'value': [100, 150, 300]})
```

How can I do this?

And how can I drop column A after reordering, so that I get the new df:

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'name': ['C', 'B'],
                'value': [150, 300]})
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do `sort_values` then slice the df by position with `iloc`

```
out = df.sort_values('value').iloc[1:]
Out[190]: 
  name  value
2    C    150
1    B    300
```